# DRIVER_STATE_POWER_FAILURE after BIOS upgrade

Tags: windows-10, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo Ideapad 330 15IKB, with Windows 10. Some time ago, I got a message that I had a BIOS update. I updated. since then, I sometimes get blue screen of death, with the message `DRIVER_STATE_POWER_FAILURE`. For example, when I try to close the Android Studio emulator, it happens. And also - sometimes, when I play Fortnite - sometimes it suddenly closes itself with an error. When I try to open it again - I get this screen after a few minutes.

My warranty is already over. When I came to a computer technician, he said that he could downgrade my BIOS version, but it might be dangerous and it might burn the motherboard.

Do some have an idea what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: “it might be dangerous and it might burn the motherboard.” - find a different technician who knows what they are talking about, because it’s clear, whoever you took it to doesn’t know what they are talking about

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which in turn killed the motherboard. Fad to call for warranty replacement and now working again, but the same BSOD still recur after heavy programs. The tech person claims it could be lack of adequate RAM. So solution might be to increase RAM to 8 or 16GB.